# Image cannot be displayed because it contains errors

Tags: static-resources, images

I have a page that contains images stored in static resources.  They are inconsistently displaying.  I just tried to manually display the image that isn't displaying.  I receive the message:
The image "https://niimbl.force.com/sfsites/c/resource/niimblLightning/images/Logo-CarnegieMellonUniversity.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Thoughts?  I would say the file is corrupted, but the images are sometimes loading & sometimes not - after refreshes.

[image]

Comment: So I looked at another image on your website (https://niimbl.force.com/sfsites/c/resource/niimblLightning/images/NIIMBL-logo-horiz@2x.png) and it seems to be resolving ok. Can you verify two things, the mime-type of the resource being referenced, and the visibility (Public vs. Private)

Comment: I tried three different browsers and they all display the image just fine for me. Did you try removing your browser cache? To be honest I don't think that will help, but it's worth a shot. Otherwise I'd assume it's a problem on the Salesforce side. If your in a real rush to get it fixed you could try uploading the image as a different static resource. Otherwise I'd just wait to see if it'll resolve itself.